# Radius search in list of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, grid, coordinates

I'm using python 2.7 and numpy (`import numpy as np`).
I have a list of x-y coordinates in the following shape:
`coords = np.zeros((100, 2), dtype=np.int)`
I have a list of values corresponding to these coordinates:
`values = np.zeros(100, dtype=np.int)`
My program is populating these arrays.

Now, for each coordinate, I want to find neighbours within radius `r` that have a non-zero value. What's the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: shouldn't `values` shape be `(100,100)`?

Comment: @filippo no. you can basically think of `coords` as the x,y coordinates and `values` is the z coordinate. They are all of length 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
```

---

```
In [101]: np.random.seed(123)

In [102]: coords = np.random.rand(20, 2)

In [103]: r = 0.3

In [104]: d = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(coords)))

In [105]: d
Out[105]:
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10        11        12  \
0   0.000000  0.539313  0.138885  0.489671  0.240183  0.566555  0.343214  0.541508  0.525761  0.295906  0.566702  0.326087  0.045059
1   0.539313  0.000000  0.509028  0.765644  0.299834  0.212418  0.535287  0.253292  0.378472  0.305322  0.504946  0.501173  0.545672
2   0.138885  0.509028  0.000000  0.369830  0.240542  0.484970  0.459329  0.449965  0.591335  0.217102  0.434730  0.187983  0.100192
3   0.489671  0.765644  0.369830  0.000000  0.579235  0.639118  0.827519  0.585140  0.946945  0.474554  0.383486  0.266724  0.444612
4   0.240183  0.299834  0.240542  0.579235  0.000000  0.364005  0.335128  0.355671  0.368796  0.148598  0.482379  0.327450  0.251218
5   0.566555  0.212418  0.484970  0.639118  0.364005  0.000000  0.676135  0.055591  0.576447  0.272729  0.315123  0.399127  0.555655
6   0.343214  0.535287  0.459329  0.827519  0.335128  0.676135  0.000000  0.679527  0.281035  0.481218  0.813671  0.621056  0.387169
7   0.541508  0.253292  0.449965  0.585140  0.355671  0.055591  0.679527  0.000000  0.602427  0.245620  0.261309  0.350237  0.526773
8   0.525761  0.378472  0.591335  0.946945  0.368796  0.576447  0.281035  0.602427  0.000000  0.498845  0.811462  0.695304  0.559738
9   0.295906  0.305322  0.217102  0.474554  0.148598  0.272729  0.481218  0.245620  0.498845  0.000000  0.333842  0.208528  0.282959
10  0.566702  0.504946  0.434730  0.383486  0.482379  0.315123  0.813671  0.261309  0.811462  0.333842  0.000000  0.254850  0.533784
11  0.326087  0.501173  0.187983  0.266724  0.327450  0.399127  0.621056  0.350237  0.695304  0.208528  0.254850  0.000000  0.288072
12  0.045059  0.545672  0.100192  0.444612  0.251218  0.555655  0.387169  0.526773  0.559738  0.282959  0.533784  0.288072  0.000000
13  0.339648  0.350100  0.407307  0.769145  0.202592  0.501132  0.185248  0.511020  0.186913  0.347808  0.678357  0.527288  0.372879
14  0.530211  0.104003  0.473790  0.689158  0.303486  0.109841  0.589377  0.149459  0.468906  0.257676  0.404710  0.431203  0.527905
15  0.622118  0.178856  0.627453  0.923461  0.391044  0.387645  0.509836  0.431502  0.273610  0.450269  0.683313  0.656742  0.639993
16  0.337079  0.211995  0.297111  0.582175  0.113238  0.251168  0.434076  0.246505  0.403684  0.107671  0.409858  0.316172  0.337886
17  0.271897  0.311029  0.313864  0.668400  0.097022  0.424905  0.252905  0.426640  0.279160  0.243693  0.576241  0.422417  0.296806
18  0.664617  0.395999  0.554151  0.592343  0.504234  0.184188  0.833801  0.157951  0.758223  0.376555  0.212643  0.410605  0.642698
19  0.328445  0.719013  0.238085  0.186618  0.476045  0.642499  0.671657  0.594990  0.828653  0.413697  0.465589  0.245340  0.284878

          13        14        15        16        17        18        19
0   0.339648  0.530211  0.622118  0.337079  0.271897  0.664617  0.328445
1   0.350100  0.104003  0.178856  0.211995  0.311029  0.395999  0.719013
2   0.407307  0.473790  0.627453  0.297111  0.313864  0.554151  0.238085
3   0.769145  0.689158  0.923461  0.582175  0.668400  0.592343  0.186618
4   0.202592  0.303486  0.391044  0.113238  0.097022  0.504234  0.476045
5   0.501132  0.109841  0.387645  0.251168  0.424905  0.184188  0.642499
6   0.185248  0.589377  0.509836  0.434076  0.252905  0.833801  0.671657
7   0.511020  0.149459  0.431502  0.246505  0.426640  0.157951  0.594990
8   0.186913  0.468906  0.273610  0.403684  0.279160  0.758223  0.828653
9   0.347808  0.257676  0.450269  0.107671  0.243693  0.376555  0.413697
10  0.678357  0.404710  0.683313  0.409858  0.576241  0.212643  0.465589
11  0.527288  0.431203  0.656742  0.316172  0.422417  0.410605  0.245340
12  0.372879  0.527905  0.639993  0.337886  0.296806  0.642698  0.284878
13  0.000000  0.408426  0.339019  0.274263  0.105627  0.668252  0.643427
14  0.408426  0.000000  0.282070  0.194058  0.345013  0.294029  0.663142
15  0.339019  0.282070  0.000000  0.344028  0.355134  0.568361  0.854775
16  0.274263  0.194058  0.344028  0.000000  0.181494  0.399730  0.513362
17  0.105627  0.345013  0.355134  0.181494  0.000000  0.581128  0.551910
18  0.668252  0.294029  0.568361  0.399730  0.581128  0.000000  0.649183
19  0.643427  0.663142  0.854775  0.513362  0.551910  0.649183  0.000000
```

result:

```
In [107]: d[(0 < d) & (d < r)].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().index.tolist())
Out[107]:
0                       [2, 4, 9, 12, 17]
1                   [4, 5, 7, 14, 15, 16]
2               [0, 4, 9, 11, 12, 16, 19]
3                                [11, 19]
4            [0, 1, 2, 9, 12, 13, 16, 17]
5                   [1, 7, 9, 14, 16, 18]
6                             [8, 13, 17]
7               [1, 5, 9, 10, 14, 16, 18]
8                         [6, 13, 15, 17]
9     [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17]
10                            [7, 11, 18]
11                  [2, 3, 9, 10, 12, 19]
12               [0, 2, 4, 9, 11, 17, 19]
13                      [4, 6, 8, 16, 17]
14               [1, 5, 7, 9, 15, 16, 18]
15                             [1, 8, 14]
16         [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 13, 14, 17]
17            [0, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16]
18                         [5, 7, 10, 14]
19                         [2, 3, 11, 12]
dtype: object
```

Comment: great answer although it doesn't incorporate the `values` dimension and requires a `pdist` which is expensive for large matrices.

Comment: @isthisthat, to incorporate the `values` you can do: `d[(values != 0) & (d < r)]...`. AFAIK pdist is one of the _fastest_ ways to calculate pairwise distances, but it might require a lot of additional RAM. I think you can't have both efficient solution in terms of speed __and__ in terms of memory usage. I might be wrong though...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this only in numpy and scipy, I find it faster.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import numpy

SIZE=512
N_PARTICLE=100
RADIUS = 15
VALUE_THRESHOLD = 0

coords = numpy.random.randint(0, SIZE, size=(N_PARTICLE, 2))
values = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, (N_PARTICLE))

square_dist = squareform(pdist(coords, metric='euclidean'))

condlist = []
for i, row in enumerate(square_dist[:]):
    condlist.append(numpy.where((values>VALUE_THRESHOLD) & (row < RADIUS) & (row > 0))[0].tolist())
```

It must be a better way to do it thoughtfully.